# Different coverage statistics for Set and Map for similar utility methods

Tags: java, unit-testing, set, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am using `jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.8` to find the code coverage in our code.

Code of the class under test is as :

```
public class Utils {

    public static boolean isNotNullOrEmpty(Map map) {
        return map != null && !map.isEmpty();
    }

    public static boolean isNotNullOrEmpty(Set set) {
        return set != null && !set.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

For which I wrote a unit tests as follows -

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

class UtilsTest {

    @Test
    void testUtils() {
        assertNotNull(new Utils());
        assertFalse(Utils.isNotNullOrEmpty(new HashMap()), "Map utils failure.");
        assertFalse(Utils.isNotNullOrEmpty(new HashSet()), "Set utils failure.");
    }
}
```

Now when these tests are executed successfully, I end up getting 50% coverage for the `isNotNullOrEmpty(Set set)` while 100% for `isNotNullOrEmpty(Map map)`. Please refer the image below - 
[image]

I've tried adding the statements as follows -

```
Set<String> nullSet = null;
assertFalse(Utils.isNotNullOrEmpty(nullSet), "Set utils failure.");
```

yet this results in same amount of coverage.

Why is this so and how can this be fixed?

In case required, I am using `junit-jupiter-api:5.0.0-M4` along with `junit-platform-surefire-provider:1.0.0-M4` and `junit-jupiter-engine:5.0.0-M4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was explained in https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/516 : there was another test that was indirectly calling method `isNotNullOrEmpty(Map map)`.